# how to run application on real device in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I have installed Blackberry on Windows7. I got all three .csi files from BB. I have done all the procedures and got a successful response from there. Then i right clicked my project and clicked on "sign with signature tool". After signing i loaded this project on Blackberry Bold Device.

Now My Device Shows the installed icon on screen but when i try to open this project it says that **"attempts to access a secure api."** how to resolve this problem.

For resolving this problem i have also Disabled my UAC. I am working on eclipse Helios.I installed Blackberry Plugin with this exe file. "**BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.5.0_helios**" is there a problem with this setup.

I am not able to launch a simple helloworld application on Device. I have tried all the help from internet but still i have not succeeded. plz help to resolve this critical issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sign your application. Contact RIM for signing keys. Install them and sign your app before installing on actual device.

Check this link to obtain signing keys: https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

Comment: i have already signed with all the three keys as i have mentioned above. i got three .csi file BB ie. 1.client-RBB-1925900356 2.client-RCR-1925900356  3.client-RRT-1925900356  i have signed with all this three keys.

Comment: As you have your application signed, then this errors should not occur when you run your app on the actual device. If you have application signed (when you close SignatureTool there is no message that you left unsigned sections), and your app still raises this error, then contact RIM via devsupport@rim.com